# Does this code fall into a design pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns

`CustomDialog` is the parent abstract class for `OkExclamationDialog` and `ExclamationDialog` with abstract method `displayDialog()` being overriden.

Does this fall into a design pattern?  Can this design be improved upon?

`JudgeButton` controls the other classes.

```
public class JudgeButton {
    private int typeCode;

    private void initialise(){
        setTypeCode();
        if(typeCode == 0){
            c = new ExclamationDialog("Episode not started");
            c.displayDialog();
        }
        else if(typeCode == 1){
            c = new OkExclamationDialog("Episode Finished, you will now be redirected");
            c.displayDialog();
        }
    }

    private void setTypeCode(){
        wrapperJsonObject = Utils.getCurrentWrapperJsonObjectFromServer();
        jsonObject = wrapperJsonObject.getJsonObject();
        NextRatingsScreen n = new NextRatingsScreen(jsonObject);
        RatingsCountDownTime r = new RatingsCountDownTime();

        if(!n.isEpisodeStarted()){
            typeCode = 0;
        }
        else if(!n.isPerformanceStarted()){
            typeCode = 1;
        }
    }
}

public class OkExclamationDialog extends CustomDialog{
    public OkExclamationDialog(String text) {
        super(text);
    }

    public void displayDialog() {
        DialogType dialogType = new DialogType();
        DialogBuilder dialogBuilder = new DialogBuilder();
        AbstractDialogFactory abstractDialogFactory = dialogType.getDialogType(DialogEnum.EXCLAMATION_DIALOG);
        Dialog nextScreen = dialogBuilder.buildDialog(abstractDialogFactory, super.getText());
        int result = nextScreen.doModal();
        ScreenController.displayNextScreenFadeTransition(nextScreen);

        if(result==Dialog.OK)
        {
            ScreenController.displayNextScreenFadeTransition(new ContestantsScreen());
        }
    }
}

public class ExclamationDialog extends CustomDialog{
    public ExclamationDialog(String text) {
        super(text);
    }

    public void displayDialog() {
        DialogType dialogType = new DialogType();
        DialogBuilder dialogBuilder = new DialogBuilder();
        AbstractDialogFactory abstractDialogFactory = dialogType.getDialogType(DialogEnum.EXCLAMATION_DIALOG);
        Dialog nextScreen = dialogBuilder.buildDialog(abstractDialogFactory, super.getText());

        ScreenController.displayNextScreenFadeTransition(nextScreen);
    }
}

public abstract class CustomDialog {
    private String text;

    public CustomDialog(String text){
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText(){
        return this.text;
    }

    public abstract void displayDialog();
}
```

Comment: What happened to your code?  Did you not grab all of it when you cut and pasted it?

Comment: I've added more code, will this suffice ?

Comment: You cold use decorator pattern here is example http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternDecorator.aspx

Comment: The variable `r` is never used, so just `new RatingsCountDownTime();` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `initialise` reminds me a factory but it's not exactly a factory. It's fine if you don't use the same if-elseif structure in your code elsewhere. If you do pull out it to a factory class.

Just some idea:

1, Consider using an `enum` instead of the integer `typeCode` (eliminate magic numbers).

2, Maybe you should throw an `IllegalStateException` in the end of the `initialise` method with a message `"Invalid typecode"`.

3, The same is true for the `setTypeCode()` method. Or set explicitly `typeCode` to `0` in the last line of the method if `0` is a valid value. (This is the implicit default value of the `private int typeCode` field.)

4, I'd rename the `setTypeCode()` to `calculateTypeCode()` which would return a `TypeCode` enum. Now it's more or less temporal coupling.

5, You should create a new `getNextScreen()` method in the `CustomDialog` class with the first four line of the `displayDialog()` method. Then call the `getNextScreen()` from the `displayDialog()` methods. It would remove some code duplication.

```
// CustomDialog class code
public Dialog createNextScreen() {
    DialogType dialogType = new DialogType();
    DialogBuilder dialogBuilder = new DialogBuilder();
    AbstractDialogFactory abstractDialogFactory = 
        dialogType.getDialogType(DialogEnum.EXCLAMATION_DIALOG);
    Dialog nextScreen = dialogBuilder.buildDialog(abstractDialogFactory, text);
    return nextScreen;
}
```

```
// OkExclamationDialog, ExclamationDialog class code
public void displayDialog() {
    Dialog nextScreen = getNextScreen();
    ...
    ScreenController.displayNextScreenFadeTransition(nextScreen);
}
```